# Is the object-code of C++ templates duplicated in executables and dynamic libraries?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, elf, object-code

A library uses a template class `TemplCls<TArg>`, and a linked executable also uses it. Now, if two source files of the same final binary (library or executable) use the template with the same parameter, then only one instantiation of the template will be kept.

What will happen if the dynamic-library and the executable both use the template? As the linker of the executable will (generally) receive a terminal option to link with the dynamic library, will it also keep in mind that the template was already instantiated in the library itself, and therefore, it need not, instantiate it into the executable?

Comment: The "One Definition Rule" ensures that there's only one instance of each method of each instantiated template class. This detail gets taken care of by your C++ implementation's compiler and linker, and not something that one needs to be concerned about.

Comment: I'm actually creating a C++ OS kernel. I need to be concerned about that to see whether object-code will increase size in multiple kernel modules rather than only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen if the dynamic-library and the executable both use the template?

Each will get get a copy of every template method that is used.

You don't need to *ask* this question, you could just *look* (in unstripped binaries):

```
nm -AC a.out foo.so | grep TemplCls
```